# react-native-ble-plx works fine on iOS emulator but crashes on boot on iOS device

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I am trying to make a react native app with react-native-ble-plx. It works fine on an iOS emulator but crashes on boot when actually put on my iPhone. After some testing, I found that removing the page with the bluetooth stops it from crashing. How do you even go about debugging an error like this, it feels like I can't even get an error if I look for one?

Comment: There will be a crash message.  Have you included the required Bluetooth privacy string in your info.plist file?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong when I couldn't find a crash message. I was building the "release" version instead of the "debug" version in the scheme menu.